# Ctrl + J doesn't work

Tags: mesh, physics, shortcut

Currently I'm using the 'Cell Fracture Add-on' and want to remove the doubles. To do that I have to make all fractures into one single object so that I'm able to go into *Edit Mode*. Normally you only need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, but somehow nothing happens.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: One of the objects has to be an active object

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are in Blender keyboard preset, not in Maya or 3DS Max keyboard shortcuts, then you will be able to do that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: In both default Maya and 3DS Max shortcut presets Ctrl+J is used for joining objects, this won't be a problem